# Launch Parameters for Windows 10 3D Viewer

Tags: .net, 3d, windows-10-universal

I want to use the Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync() method to start Windows 10 3D Viewer passing a .3mf file for it to open.

I know that the Schema for the Uri should be "com.microsoft.3dviewer:" but what I cannot workout is the format of the parameter to pass a local file to 3D viewer. What format should the filename parameter take? I have tried simply appending the filename after the schema (e.g. com.microsoft.3dviewer:myfile.3mf) but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution provided by Yan Gu - MSFT on the Microsoft support forums was to use the Launcher.LaunchFileAsync() method instead of LaunchUriAsync() method. This worked for me.

His answer is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/198910/launching-3d-viewer-with-filename.html?childToView=200247#answer-200247)